# Pass form data through re-orderable table rows

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drag-and-drop

I am attempting to create a form that allows for a few different things to happen. The user will be able to add/remove rows, and click to edit the text and each row. Each row has two columns, a 'title' and an 'entry' - for example a title might be 'name' and an entry might be 'John Doe'. I plan on using Javascript to handle adding and removing the table rows, and click to edit of both the title and the entry. I have included a mockup of what I have in mind below:

[image: Form/Table Mockup]

The problem I have run into is how to pass the data from the table through the form using POST. Is this even possible? I would need to pass the following info: the total number of rows, the order/position of the row, the 'title' text, and the 'entry'. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I am pretty stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact structure, a possible method of solving this issue is to have a hidden field on each row that stores the id in an input with the name `title[]`.

When retrieving the POST an array should be passed with the values in the correct order.

Comment: The exact structure of the form you mean? So far it just looks like this: http://pastebin.com/yE8bKEXg

Hidden values sound like they might be the solution, could you provide a brief example of that in action? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure of the possible technical issues of the form post you will have to test if they actually change order but you just stick a `<input type="hidden" value="whatever" />` in the last `td` of each `tr`. The form should post all of the values in the correct order if the `tr`s are changed when you drag them around.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I am still a bit confused though. Would I need two separate values for each row (one for title and one for entry)? And then I would use JS to change the hidden values when the <td>'s are updated?

Comment: I took another look I see what you are saying now. There should no need for a hidden field, change the names of the inputs for title to `title[]` and `entry[]` once you "save" the entries they should POST arrays in the correct order